# Guest VMs Unknown after power outage on HP VSA

Tags: vmware-esxi, electrical-power, outage, hp

A remote office had a power outage tonight.  When the power came up, both the Physical DC and the Physical ESXi Server came up.  Connecting to vSphere,  I can see the HP-VSA has started, but the other guests say Unknown, and the log states that the configuration cannot be found. The VMs' LUNS are hosted on the VSA I have tried rescan-all for the Storage and Storage adapter.
A quick google indicates that the Rescan should work.

I have a call in to my support engineer, but figured I check here while I wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with our support engineer for a while, re-scanning the storage adapters, datastores, etc and checking the network connections, the iSCSI connections, etc, we finally decided to try a reboot of the host machine.

After the host came up and the VSA VM started,  I did a Storage Adapter Re-scan, and all the VM's came up.